# Why doesnt my header stay under my content?

Tags: html, css, footer, sticky-footer

No matter what I try my footer stays on the bottom of my screen and not after my content like I need it to be. Its stays at the bottom of my screen and over my content that it's supposed to be under. I put my header (not in the jsfiddle), content, and footer div inside a wrapper that has 100% height. here is the jsfiddle [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9L58eyqt/) The footer doesnt even show up on the fiddle!!!!

**CSS**

```css
body{

    background-color: #555;
    margin: 0;   
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;

}

#wrapper{
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}

#content{
    top: 140px;
    position: absolute;
    height: 90%;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    padding-bottom: -70px;
}

#content h2{
    text-align: center; ;
    color: white;
    margin: 50px auto;
    width: 60%;
}

/*Footer*/
#footer{
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;   
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
    }

#footer p{
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
    
<body>

<div id="wrapper">

<div id="header"></div>  

<a href="restaurant_reserve.php"><button id="reserve-button" class="w3-btn-block w3-hover-white" style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 15px; position: fixed; top: 100px; z-index: 999;">Reserve Now!</button></a>

<div id="content">

    <img style="width: 100%; height: auto;" src="images/slider/examples/slide-example3.png">

<h2><strong>Come and devour Friendz' hunger satisfying selection of the
    most delectable soul foods around!</strong>
</h2>

<div class="info-block1">
    <img src="images/restaurant_examples/example1.jpg" title="Chicken breast with veggies" alt="Chicken breast with veggies">
    <p> Come and enjoy our delicious chicken breast and vegetables. This is just test text that is
    be used for demonstration and to take up space.</p>   
</div>

<div class="info-block2">
    <img src="images/restaurant_examples/example2.jpg" title="Some type of food" alt="example2">
    <p> This is just generic text. I am writing and typing this off of the top of my head
    and it is meant just to take up space.</p>   
</div>

<div class="info-block1">
    <img src="images/restaurant_examples/example3.jpg" title="Some type of food" alt="example2">
    <p>This is even more generic text that is being used to take up 
        space and demonstrate potential formatting of the website.</p>
</div>

<div class="info-block2">
    <img src="images/restaurant_examples/example4.jpg" title="Some type of food" alt="example2">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, fabulas phaedrum mea no, an eum utinam 
        libris dictas, audire expetenda eu quo.
    </p>
</div>

</div>

<div id="footer">
    <p>Footer Test</p>
</div>

</div><!--end wrapper div-->


</body>
</html>
```

Please help

Comment: The #header is not defined in your JSFiddle, also it has no content so by default there's nothing to show. Try rephrasing your question or positing relevant code.

Comment: Sorry @rsn i meant FOOTER not header

Comment: If you want the footer to appear after the content, then why have you given it an absolution position? Just remove the `position:absolute`, `bottom:0` and `left:0` properties from the `#footer` rule.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change the #footer's 'position' to **relative**.
2. Put the #footer div inside the #content div.

Why are you setting the z-index for the #footer if you want it *after* the content instead of *over*? Also, get rid of your inline css, that's what .css files are for..